# No matching function call for timer?

Tags: library

I am using the Timer library here with the Adafruit feather m0: 
https://github.com/JChristensen/Timer 
https://playground.arduino.cc/code/timer 
I cannot figure out why I am getting the error:

no matching function for call to 'Timer::every(int, void (&)())'

Here is that part of the code:

```
void setup(){
      everyAlt = t.every(100, readAltimeter);
      everyLaunch = t.every(500, detectLaunch);
      t.oscillate(blueled, 500, HIGH);
    }


    void readAltimeter(){
      alts[altPlace] = bmp.readAltitude()-zeroAlt;
      altPlace++;
    }


    void detectLaunch(){
      tempSpeed = 0;
      int x = 0;
      while (x < 5){
        tempSpeed += abs((alts[x]-alts[x+1])*10);
      }
      if (tempSpeed/5 > 5){
        t.stop(everyLaunch);
      }
    }
```

I am pretty new to arduino so any help would be much appriciated!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with this code: https://pastebin.com/WQBCb1AQ Does the code above compile correctly?

Comment: Yea, I still have the same compiling error. https://pastebin.com/W63QC2r4

Comment: You and me are using two different versions of the library. The `every` function has e.g. an overload `int8_t every(unsigned long period, void (*callback)(void*), void* context);` in your library but not the current master version (https://github.com/JChristensen/Timer/blob/master/Timer.h#L40). Please uninstall your old Timer library from the library manager, download the newest ZIP from the Github repo, reinstall the lib and retry.

Answer (score 2):

Had the wrong version. Correct version downloaded from the current master: github.com/JChristensen/Timer